# What type of logical argument is this?

Tags: logic

I'm currently doing  an A-Level (UK) refresher course and this question came up as part of a multiple choice assessment for the Proof module.

[image]

The other options were other common 'categories' of proof such as by Exhaustion, Contradiction, etc but I can't for the life of me see how this is anything but a direct proof by deduction. Can anyone perhaps offer any insight on this?

Comment: You are right to be puzzled... Maybe [Direct proof](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Direct_proof): "a way of showing the truth or falsehood of a given statement by a straightforward combination of established facts, usually axioms, existing lemmas and theorems, without making any further assumptions. In order to directly prove a conditional statement of the form "If p, then q", it suffices to consider the situations in which the statement p is true.

Comment: But in a sense, Yes: a direct proof is a *deduction* of the conclusion from already established "facts": axioms, theorems, lemma.

Comment: I just checked and the other three options are 'Proof by Exhaustion', 'Proof by Contradiction' and 'Proof by Counter Example'... If the truth of A necessitates the falsehood of Z then that's just direct proof. So these other options make no sense, right?

Comment: Correct........

Comment: The proof is incomplete. It is missing an assertion that A *is* true.